# Unable to deploy C++ Builder project

Tags: c++, c++builder

If someone knows why I'm not having the option to deploy the project, please help out..the option is not available at the moment, I don't know why...

Here's the image of how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: is that feature available in the community edition?

Comment: yes there's, and now it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you setup the [Deployment Manager](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Deployment_Manager) first?

Per the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Project_Deploy) for the `Deploy` menu item:

> Deploys the current platform and target, **once it is set up in the deployment manager**.

So, you can't `Deploy` if you haven't defined what to deploy to.

In your screenshot, the `Deployment` menu item, which invokes the Deployment Manager, is not disabled.

Comment: Thankx....it worked...yeah I hadn't set up the deployment manager